# Firebase rule for one property of node

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

my user database contains all users with data like username, rating, description, email.

I want to access all user but, want to set email to be unreadable. Is it possible to set just one property to not be readable?

this is my rule:

```
"users": {
      ".indexOn": ["username","id"],
      ".write": false,
      ".read": true, //removed
       "$user_id":{
            "email": {
            ".read": false,
            },
        }
    },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible with Firebase Realtime Database. Once a user can read a node, they can read all data inside that node.

You'll want to instead separate the emails into their own top-level node, where you then control access on the entire node.

For more on this see:

- [How to block reading specific field in child in the firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57737413/how-to-block-reading-specific-field-in-child-in-the-firebase/57740823#57740823)